# 'Pseudo-Relativistic' behavior in Graphene

Tags: condensed-matter, graphene

I've read that electrons in Graphene behave 'pseudo-relativistically'; what does this mean? how do they behave differently from electrons in other materials?

Answer (score 2):

Electrons near the band edge are a little interesting in graphene, because their dispersion relation goes like $\omega \sim k$ instead of $\omega \sim k^2$ as they do for massive particles. The bands actually touch in graphene, and so are linear at the band edge. Graphene electrons propagate like massless particles with a fixed velocity $v_0$ regardless of their momentum if they are near the band edge, so you get "massless" charged particle motion.

Edit: As an addendum, here's a pretty good note by Leggett about graphene and why this band structure happens: https://uwaterloo.ca/institute-for-quantum-computing/sites/ca.institute-for-quantum-computing/files/uploads/files/lecture-5.pdf